# Async CTP, unit testing a ViewModel's async Method

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, async-ctp

I have a unit test (using MSTest) like so:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest()
{
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
    viewModel.Run();
    //Assert something here
}
```

Run is an async method that returns void.

Let's say `Run` is implemented like so:

```
public async void Run()
{
    //Show a busy indicator here

    try
    {
        var result = await myAsyncModelClass.LongRunningOperation();

        //Use the results here
    }
    finally
    {
        //Hide the busy indicator here
    }
}
```

`myAsyncModelClass.LongRunningOperation()`, is itself an async method that returns some `Task<T>` where T is the result my ViewModel is interested in.

My issue, is that my test is running the `Run` method asynchronously, so the my assertions are called before the `Run` methods completes.  It is odd, b/c the finally block is never reached when I put a breakpoint, since the assertions fail.  How can I keep the `Run` method synchronous to be able to unit test it?

I have a unit test of `myAsyncModelClass.LongRunningOperation()` also, but I merely call `Task<T>.Wait()` since it returns a task.  This makes it synchronous when unit testing.

Also, I would like to mention, `Run()` is invoke by an ICommand magically by an MVVM framework.  `void` may or may not be a require return type, I will have to try it out.

Comment: Hi - I have no experience with the C#-async (killed my VS installation) but can you call Run if it's a async function? F# has some similar constructs but there you would get an compile-error if you tried to call an asycn-object. - Anyhow why don't you just wrap this into a Task and await it (or your await in your Test)?

Comment: I would return a task, but this method is also invoked by an MVVM framework via a binding to an ICommand.  I don't believe my code will get executed in my application if I make that change.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Async methods need a context to "return to". Since MSTests run on the thread pool, by default the async methods all continue on a thread pool thread as well (and do not block the MSTest method).

Under the `(C# Testing) Unit Testing` sample (in your Async CTP install directory), there's a type called `GeneralThreadAffineContext`, which can be used as such:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest()
{
  MyViewModel viewModel = null;
  GeneralThreadAffineContext.Run(() =>
  {
    viewModel = new MyViewModel();
    viewModel.Run();
  });
  //Assert something here
}
```

There are also specific WPF and WinForms contexts, but the thread-affine context should work for general ViewModels (that don't make explicit use of `Dispatcher`).

**Update 2012-02-05:** If you can change your ViewModel method to return `Task`, then you have another option: the new [AsyncUnitTests library](http://asyncunittests.codeplex.com/). Install that NuGet package, change your `TestClass` to `AsyncTestClass`, and your async unit tests can be written much more naturally:

```
[TestMethod]
public async void MyTest()
{
  MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();
  await viewModel.Run();
  //Assert something here
}
```

**Update 2012-09-04:** Visual Studio 2012 includes `async` unit testing, so you don't need the `AsyncUnitTests` library anymore:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task MyTest()
{
  MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();
  await viewModel.Run();
  //Assert something here
}
```

Comment: That works great.  I think I'm going to build my own implementation of `GeneralThreadAffineContext`, however.

Comment: If you're interested, I've released mine as [part of](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext) the Nito.AsyncEx library, called `AsyncContext`.

Comment: It would be nicer if there was a way for it to be hooked up globally for each unit test.  Like if you could just put the `async` keyword on your unit test and MSTest take care of it.  Maybe in full C# 5 we'll get something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Since Visual Studio 2012 MSTest supports async test methods. Just remeber they should return Task instead of void:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task MyTest()
{
  MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();
  await viewModel.Run();
  //Assert something here
}
```